# Single-line query to select some items if All() returned true

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to write a single-line query to select some items of a collection if the Linq function `All` returned true for that collection? My question arises from the fact that `All()` returns a boolean value, and not the initial list.

I'll give a short example. Say we have a list of accounts:

```
class Account
{
     public DateTime? CloseDate { get; set; }
     public decimal? AmountOnCloseDate { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to have a single-line query that selects accounts (from a given accounts list) with `AmountOnCloseDate` larger than some given value, but only if all the accounts have their `CloseDate` larger than some given value?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want, could you show us an example of what you would like to do?

Comment: Does this count as a single-line? `selectedAccounts = accounts.All(x => x.CloseDate.Value > 1) ? Enumerable.Empty<Account>() : account.Where(x => x.AmountOnClaseData > 1);`

Comment: @TheLethalCoder, see example in Mateusz Krzaczek's comment.

Comment: @MateuszKrzaczek, no, since it is essentially an if-else.

Comment: You could always do the `Where`s and then `Count` the resultant `List` but you're still going to have to have the `if` to see if it matches the original.

Comment: @HeyJude Added a method that does not use if else (also not a ternary operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, only thing you have to do is assign it to a new list as you want it to remain empty if `.All()` fails:

```
List<Example> newList = 
    (originalList.All( r => r.A > 5 )) 
    ?originalList.Where( r => r.B > 1 ).ToList()
    : new List<Example>();
```

Or you could do the `.All()` check in the where, that would **DRASTICALLY** decrease performance but doesn't require the ternary operator.

```
List<Point> newL = originalList
    .Where( r => r.X > 34 && originalList.All( t => t.Y > 241 ) )
    .ToList();
```

**Disclaimer:** There is no advantages of doing this in 1 line, only disadvantages. In real world scenarios I will always advice against doing this, and just suggest the if.

**Hint:** *stick to the if*

Comment: This is single line but less readable than a normal if statement.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Thats not the question

Comment: True but I'd rather have more readable code than shorter code and I'd hope most developers would.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder In production I too would just use if :) Readability means less maintenance usually

Comment: Can you put a massive "DO NOT USE THIS SECOND METHOD" disclaimer in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible, the closest you will get is having an `if` on the `All` and then the `Select`:

```
if (accountList.All(a => a.CloseDate.Value > someValue))
{
    var result = accountList.Where(a => a.AmountOnCloseDate > someOtherValue);
}
```

Note that I would caution you to stay with a normal `if` statement for this as the ternary becomes less readable.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any C# statement/block/program that can't be made "single line" (except [`#`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691094(v=vs.71).aspx) directives)

```
var result = new[] { accounts }.Where(g => g.All(a => a.CloseDate > DateTime.Now))
            .SelectMany(g => g).Where(a => a.AmountOnCloseDate > 42).ToList();
```